# Error while I deploy my Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I developed an app with RStudio. On my laptop it works pretty well, but when I try to deploy it to Shiny server, I get an error.
Below the message I retrieve. I installed both rNVD3 and rjson packages, that according to the message seem to have problems.
Can anyone help?

```
################################ Begin Task Log ################################ 
[2015-12-23T19:33:50.691657809+0000] Installing R package: registry (0.3)
* installing to library <U+2018>/usr/local/lib/R/site-library<U+2019>
* installing *binary* package <U+2018>registry<U+2019> ...
* DONE (registry)
[2015-12-23T19:33:50.992761317+0000] Installing R package: digest (0.6.8)
* installing to library <U+2018>/usr/local/lib/R/site-library<U+2019>
* installing *binary* package <U+2018>digest<U+2019> ...
* DONE (digest)
[2015-12-23T19:33:51.294593635+0000] Installing R package: whisker (0.3-2)
* installing to library <U+2018>/usr/local/lib/R/site-library<U+2019>
* installing *binary* package <U+2018>whisker<U+2019> ...
* DONE (whisker)
[2015-12-23T19:33:51.601777554+0000] Installing R package: scatterplot3d (0.3-36)
* installing to library <U+2018>/usr/local/lib/R/site-library<U+2019>
* installing *binary* package <U+2018>scatterplot3d<U+2019> ...
* DONE (scatterplot3d)
[2015-12-23T19:33:51.918131230+0000] Installing R package: xtable (1.8-0)
* installing to library <U+2018>/usr/local/lib/R/site-library<U+2019>
* installing *binary* package <U+2018>xtable<U+2019> ...
* DONE (xtable)
[2015-12-23T19:33:52.230003490+0000] Installing R package: magrittr (1.5)
* installing to library <U+2018>/usr/local/lib/R/site-library<U+2019>
* installing *binary* package <U+2018>magrittr<U+2019> ...
* DONE (magrittr)
[2015-12-23T19:33:52.525312212+0000] Installing R package: gridBase (0.4-7)
* installing to library <U+2018>/usr/local/lib/R/site-library<U+2019>
* installing *binary* package <U+2018>gridBase<U+2019> ...
* DONE (gridBase)
[2015-12-23T19:33:52.829650380+0000] Installing R package: labeling (0.3)
* installing to library <U+2018>/usr/local/lib/R/site-library<U+2019>
* installing *binary* package <U+2018>labeling<U+2019> ...
* DONE (labeling)
[2015-12-23T19:33:53.110608764+0000] Installing R package: htmltools (0.2.6)
* installing to library <U+2018>/usr/local/lib/R/site-library<U+2019>
* installing *binary* package <U+2018>htmltools<U+2019> ...
* DONE (htmltools)
[2015-12-23T19:33:53.507345673+0000] Building R package: rNVD3 (0.0.1)
/mnt/packages/build /mnt
Warning in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
* installing to library <U+2018>/usr/local/lib/R/site-library<U+2019>
* installing *source* package <U+2018>rNVD3<U+2019> ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called <U+2018>rjson<U+2019>
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package <U+2018>rNVD3<U+2019>
* removing <U+2018>/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rNVD3<U+2019>
################################# End Task Log ################################# 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 120205071 failed: Error building image: Error building rNVD3 (0.0.1). Build exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Comment: what did you use to install rNDV3?

Comment: I used "install_github" function (activated through "devtools" package)

Comment: I think rNVD3 has been rolled into rCharts, which itself seems to have stagnated a bit... ymmv here...

Comment: this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194458/r-twitter-package-download-of-package-rjson-failed) might help. What's the R version installed on your Shiny server (I assume it's yours)?

Comment: The version of RStudio on my laptop, you mean? It's the 3.2.2

Comment: Not clear to me your previous comment (the one about rCharts). Could you please clarify?

Comment: I tried also the suggestion contained in the post you linked, but the problem persists

Comment: Where do you deploy your Shiny application? To your own R Shiny server or to shinyapps.io? You say "I installed both rNVD3 and rjson packages" - but did you do it on your local computer (through RStudio) or at R Shiny server computer?

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is that `rNVD3` package depends on `rjson` package, but does not declare it in `DESCRIPTION` file. When shiny server tries to prepare environment for your application and comes to `rNVD3`, it fails to build it because `rjson` is not available despite being required.

That should be really fixed by `rNVD3` package maintainer, but since development of that package has ceased, this will probably never happen.

But I believe that solution would be as simple as adding line

```
library('rjson')
```

on top of `server.R` file. R Shiny server should pick it up during deployment and make sure that `rjson` is available before it attempts to build `rNVD3`.